# Adding watermarks to photos

Tags: android

Oh,my first question~
Here is my problem.I'm making an Application to take photos and add a watermark to it.
First step,as the application launches,I take a shot(use the biggest resolution,like2592*1952(5M)).After the photo is taken,and I press Ok to return to my application's view,the application crashes.
But,if I take a shot as the app launches with the resolution not that big(like 3M,2M,1M),it works all right.And then,the second shot,with the resolution of 5M,it works fun either way.
I'm puzzled.Can anyone help me?
Here is some code about decoding the image file.

```
    public void onClick(View v){
                Bitmap bitmap1 =mcreateBitmap(bitmaptmp, "watermark");
//              bitmaptmp=null;
                /* Associate the Bitmap to the ImageView */
                if (bitmap1 != null) {
                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);                 
                }
                mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//              try {
//                  String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
//                  String imageFileName = JPEG_FILE_PREFIX + timeStamp;
//                  saveMyBitmap(imageFileName,bitmap1);
//                  bitmap1=null;
//              } catch (IOException e) {
//                  e.printStackTrace();
//              }   
            }
```

public Bitmap mcreateBitmap(Bitmap src, String str) {

```
    Time t = new Time();
    t.setToNow();       
    int w = src.getWidth();
    int h = src.getHeight();

    String mstrTitle = "11："+t.hour + ":" + t.minute + ":" + t.second;
    String xx="34："+x;
    String yy="44："+y;      
    Bitmap bmpTemp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmpTemp);
    Paint photoPaint = new Paint(); 
    photoPaint.setDither(true);   
    photoPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    Rect s = new Rect(0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight());
    Rect d = new Rect(0, 0, w, h);
    canvas.drawBitmap(src, s, d, photoPaint);

    String familyName = "new";
    Typeface font = Typeface.create(familyName, Typeface.BOLD);
    photoPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    photoPaint.setTypeface(font);
    photoPaint.setTextSize(18); 
    canvas.drawText(mstrTitle,40, 20, photoPaint);
    canvas.drawText(xx,40, 40, photoPaint);
    canvas.drawText(yy,40, 60, photoPaint);
    canvas.save(Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
    canvas.restore();

    return bmpTemp;
}
```

Here is logCat:
01-05 11:25:25.791: E/dalvikvm-heap(11147): 20238336-byte external allocation too large for this process.
01-05 11:25:25.791: E/dalvikvm(11147): Out of memory: Heap Size=2923KB, Allocated=2460KB, Bitmap Size=1235KB, Limit=13756KB
01-05 11:25:25.791: E/dalvikvm(11147): Trim info: Footprint=2883KB, Allowed Footprint=3267KB, Trimmed=344KB
01-05 11:25:25.791: E/GraphicsJNI(11147): VM won't let us allocate 20238336 bytes
01-05 11:25:25.801: D/AndroidRuntime(11147): Shutting down VM
01-05 11:25:25.801: W/dalvikvm(11147): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40028a00)
01-05 11:25:25.801: E/AndroidRuntime(11147): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-05 11:25:25.801: E/AndroidRuntime(11147): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
01-05 11:25:25.801: E/AndroidRuntime(11147):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
01-05 11:25:25.801: E/AndroidRuntime(11147):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:574)
01-05 11:25:25.801: E/AndroidRuntime(11147):    at com.kevin.photowatermark.PhotowatermarkActivity.mcreateBitmap(PhotowatermarkActivity.java:403)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverlow! Could you provide additional information about the crash? Like the logcat stack trace.

Comment: I wish so.But as you konw,in the emulater,you cannot use the camera.So,the only way I used is to install the app in a real device.

Comment: Run the app using the Eclipse Debugger and an USB cable and you also get logcat feedback!

Comment: Thanks a lot ,I will debug the app right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

old code:

```
 if ((targetW > 0) || (targetH > 0)) {
        scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);
```

new code:

```
if (photoH > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE || photoW> IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
        scaleFactor = (int)Math.pow(2, (int) Math.round(Math.log(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE / (double) Math.max(photoH, photoW)) / Math.log(0.5)));
```

then,it works all right.

Answer (score 1):

For Decoding the file you should use the following method.  Your issue is happens due to the Memory problem. So decode the image (Bitmap) which you captured from camera device using the below method.

```
 package com.example.stackoverflow;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MyCameraActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 



    static String str_Camera_Photo_ImagePath = "";
    private static File f;
    private static int Take_Photo = 2;
    private static String str_randomnumber = "";
    static String str_Camera_Photo_ImageName = "";
    public static String str_SaveFolderName;
    private static File wallpaperDirectory;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    int storeposition = 0;
    public static GridView gridview;
    public static ImageView imageView;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ccccc);
        this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                str_SaveFolderName = Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .getAbsolutePath()
                        + "/rajeshsample";
                str_randomnumber = String.valueOf(nextSessionId());
                wallpaperDirectory = new File(str_SaveFolderName);
                if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists())
                    wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
                str_Camera_Photo_ImageName = str_randomnumber
                        + ".jpg";
                str_Camera_Photo_ImagePath = str_SaveFolderName
                        + "/" + str_randomnumber + ".jpg";
                System.err.println(" str_Camera_Photo_ImagePath  "
                        + str_Camera_Photo_ImagePath);
                f = new File(str_Camera_Photo_ImagePath);
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(
                        MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).putExtra(
                        MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f)),
                        Take_Photo);
                System.err.println("f  " + f);
            }
        });
    }


    // used to create randon numbers
    public String nextSessionId() {
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        return new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
    }


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
        if (requestCode == Take_Photo) {
            String filePath = null;

            filePath = str_Camera_Photo_ImagePath;
            if (filePath != null) {
                Bitmap faceView = ( new_decode(new File(
                                filePath))); // ========================> good
                                                // lines



                imageView.setImageBitmap(faceView);

            } else {
                bitmap = null;
            }
        }
    } 

    public static Bitmap new_decode(File f) {

        // decode image size

        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        o.inDither = false; // Disable Dithering mode

        o.inPurgeable = true; // Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory,
                                // the Bitmap can be cleared

        o.inInputShareable = true; // Which kind of reference will be used to
                                    // recover the Bitmap data after being
                                    // clear, when it will be used in the future
        try {
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 300;
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 1.5 < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp / 1.5 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 1.5;
            height_tmp /= 1.5;
            scale *= 1.5;
        }

        // decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        // o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        o.inDither = false; // Disable Dithering mode

        o.inPurgeable = true; // Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory,
                                // the Bitmap can be cleared

        o.inInputShareable = true; // Which kind of reference will be used to
                                    // recover the Bitmap data after being
                                    // clear, when it will be used in the future
        // return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        try {

//          return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null,
//                  null);
            Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, null);
            System.out.println(" IW " + width_tmp);
            System.out.println("IHH " + height_tmp);           
               int iW = width_tmp;
                int iH = height_tmp;

               return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, iW, iH, true);

        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            // clearCache();

            // System.out.println("bitmap creating success");
            System.gc();
            return null;
            // System.runFinalization();
            // Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
            // System.gc();
            // decodeFile(f);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: you should use this method below  /* Decode the JPEG file into a Bitmap */ this comment.

Comment: yeah you can ... but according to that you have to change the above method.with the additional arguments. i have given the options with in this method itself .. so there is no need to provide that as a argument.. i hope so .

Comment: But when I used the decodeFile method,it crashed the same way..It's the same problem according to the logCat.

Comment: It seems that the problem is "out of memory".So I need to handle the heap size of my application.After searching the web,I didn't find any solution working.I'm so puzzled.

Comment: did you checked the above new code ??? that will avoid the outofmemory problem... for that only i have made that decode method.

Comment: As you know,the code of taking photo using Camera app was downloaded from http://developer.android.com/  After I installed the sample,it worked fun.

Comment: In my project,after taking photos,I add a watermark to the picture.I think the function of adding watermarks results in the crash.

Comment: I updated my question.Please check it out again.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi,I have fixed my project.It's "scaleFactor" problem.It works fun now.Thank you all the same.